# Prevent docrine from updating schema on one database

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony project using a MYSQL database. I setup a second entity manager which accesses a SQL Server database. I'd like the ability for Doctrine to read and write to both databases, which it can do now. But I'd like to prevent Doctrine from updating the database schema, if I were to make a change like that by myself.

Doctrine should not be able to add tables, remove columns, or change the name of columns in the SQL Server database. Doing so would break the legacy application that uses this database.

Is there some setting I can use to make sure the database schema won't change?

Comment: At the database level, create yourself a user(maybe call it doctrine) and restrict it from making schema changes.  Then configure doctrine to use that user.